# Spinner not displaying elements

Tags: java, android

I am trying to copy elements(name) from JSONArray into ArrayList and then from ArrayList to Spinner.I am not getting any error message but when executed Spinner is not displaying any elements. How can the Spinner display the elements?

```
package com.example.klarity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Spinner;

 import com.example.klarity1.R;

  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  Spinner practiceSpin;
  Spinner projectSpin;
  JSONObject projDet;
  JSONArray projArr;
  ArrayList<String> arrData=new ArrayList<String>();
  int[] project;



  public final static String JSON_DATA =
          "{" 
                   + "  \"project\": [" 
                   + "    {"                  
                   + "      \"name\": \"xxxx\""                   
                   + "    }," 
                   + "    {" 
                   + "      \"name\": \"yyyy\"" 
                   + "    },"                                                   //JSONArray created
                   + "    {" 
                   + "      \"name\": \"zzzz\""
                   + "    },"
                   + "    {" 
                   + "      \"name\": \"hhhh\""
                   + "    }"
                   + "  ]" 
                   + "}"; 


   @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    try {
           projDet=new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);
           projArr=projDet.getJSONArray("project");

           ArrayList<String> arrData=new ArrayList<String>();
           for(int n = 0; n < projArr.length(); n++)
           {
               //JSONObject projDet = projArr.getJSONObject(n);
                arrData.add(projArr.getJSONObject(n).getString("name"));
           }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("exception occured");
        }


    try {
        practiceSpin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPractice);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ar=   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.practices ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        practiceSpin.setAdapter(ar);

        /*projectSpin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProject);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ar1= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.projects  ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ar1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        projectSpin.setAdapter(ar1);*/

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_proj = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.array.projects, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arrData);     //"The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity, int, int, JSONArray) 
         adapter_proj.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        projectSpin.setAdapter(adapter_proj); 
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        System.out.println("exception occured in 2nd catch");
    }
    finally{

    }






}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using 2 arraylist . 1 in on create and 1 globally. Thats creating issue

Comment: Have you checked your Arraylist , its always returning empty arraylist Thats creating a problem. Apart from that you should use ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_proj = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arrData); to set your adapter. Just check out your parsing

Comment: @MRX ..Yes I resolved that error..kept only 1 arrayList which is global..Thanks for your help..debugged the code..and now all the JSONArray elements are goin into arrData ie arrayList..

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your local varibable called `arrData`: Replace

`ArrayList<String> arrData=new ArrayList<String>();`

with this

`this.arrData=new ArrayList<String>();` (remove the ArrayList ).

`arrData` exists only in the first try-cacth block, and in second try-catch block the `arrData` was acctualy the field of your class. 
I highly recommend to you to use "this" as much as possible to avoid similar problem.